# DropDownMenu with sub-menus

Tags: material-ui

I'm trying to create a dropdown menu with nested sub-menus, is that possible? what I have so far is:

```
const action2 = <DropDownMenu value={this.state.action2} onChange={this.handleChange} key={2} desktop={true}>
  <MenuItem key={1} value="1" primaryText="Refresh"/>
  <MenuItem key={2} value="2" primaryText="Send feedback"/>
  <MenuItem key={3} value="3" primaryText="Settings"/>
  <MenuItem key={4} value="4" primaryText="Help"/>
  <MenuItem key={5} value="5" primaryText="Sign out"/>
  <Divider />
  <MenuItem key={6} primaryText="Dropdown" rightIcon={<ArrowDropRight />} menuItems={[
      <MenuItem key={1} value="6" primaryText="Refresh"/>,
      <MenuItem key={2} value="7" primaryText="Send feedback"/>,
      <MenuItem key={3} value="8" primaryText="Settings"/>,
      <MenuItem key={4} value="9" primaryText="Help"/>,
      <MenuItem key={5} value="10" primaryText="Sign out"/>
    ]}/>
</DropDownMenu>;
```

This renders the dropdown with menu items, just that the "Dropdown" menu item does not render the sub-menu on click.

Is there a way to accomplish this using a dropdown menu? I also tried with IconMenu, but while the sub-menu rendered on click, it was gone just after (probably to react to tap on the Dropdown menu item)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are feeling dangerous, you can actually make this work by creating your own component on the lines of DropDownMenu. If you look inside it, it uses a Popover to host the Menu. The reason why the sub-menu's don't work is because it adds code to hide the pop-over of the click of any menu item -

```
_onMenuItemTouchTap(key, payload, e) {
 this.props.onChange(e, key, payload);

    this.setState({
      open: false,
    });
},
```

Sourced from [DropDownMenu material-ui GitHub page](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/src/DropDownMenu/DropDownMenu.jsx).

You can change this logic to not change the open state if the item has children.

You may face another challenge which I came across, Popover component doesn't expand dynamically to allow more content in some cases. I am not sure if it would clip the sub-menus or not.

Answer (score 0):

Currently (v0.14.4) you can not do that using the `DropDownMenu`..

You would be able to achieve that using the `Menu`component, but I don't think you want an inline menu, so the answer is `no, you can't accomplish that today.`